# Map response of nodes of the graph to properties of a class

Tags: java, asynchronous, design-patterns

I have a Node class which looks like this:

```
public class Node{
    List<Node> parents;
    List<Node> children;
    Response response;
    Class<? extends Response> responseType;
}
```

Each node has some kind of response. Each node is executed asynchronously. I have a callback method which is executed when the whole graph is completed.

Suppose we have a model class which has *n* properties of type `Response`.

```
public class Model{
    Response node1;
    Response node2;
    .
    .
    .
}
```

How can I map the output of the graph to the properties of the model in a configuration driven way (Reflection, Functional interface, etc)?

Example:

```
    Model model = new Model();
    model.node1 = node1.response;
    model.node2 = node2.response;
```

As we can see that mapping is manual. Is there a way I can define this mapping in a configuration and run it in generic manner?

Comment: Can you give an example of the mapping?

Comment: updated the post.

Comment: Can't you hold a collection of `Response` in `Model`?

Comment: I can do that but each node can have response of derived type and thus I will loose the type information. Each node also contains the type of response it has(Class<? extends Response). 
I can make a map, Map<Node, Response>, to solve using your approach.
But I was wondering if I can somehow map the response of each node to a property of model in a generic manner.

Comment: You'll lose type information the way you have it too because they are all `Response`. I'm not sure I understand what "generic manner" means here. We're lacking a lot of context and usage details. And what does asynchronity have to do with this?